# Provider hosted app in sharepoint openened with sharepoint modal. How to close it from inside the app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I've created a provider hosted app that runs on an azure website.
Now in sharepoint we open that page in a modal dialog as follows:

```
origin = encodeURIComponent(origin);
var pageUrl = baseUrl + '&Origin=' + origin + '&Controller=' + controller;
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.width = 800;
options.height = 1000;
options.title = 'PTW Registration Form';
options.url = pageUrl;
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, OnDialogClose);
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

This all works.
Now on our page we have a custom close button that will trigger an ajax request and then the modal should be closed.

Only problem is with the following code it doesn't do anything.

```
window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogNoRefresh', '*');
```

And with

```
window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1 /*OK*/, 'Closed with OK result');
```

it gives a security error...

Anyone who encountered something similar?